# How do you compare 1 dimension array with 2 dimension array in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, multidimensional-array

In one dimension array(In my case Backpack slots) i store all items that i have purchased.
In two dimension array i store item info(Name, id, price and power).
When i purchase item, it inserts items name in first empty array index on backpack array.
When i try to select that item, it returns wrong power.

My example:
I have 5 items in shop. If i purchase 5th(Last tier), it stores item name in backpack array, so backpack[0] is equal with item[4]. Now i need to find a solution how to access that item in backpack array, so i could get items full information, like power.

So far i have this

```
Console.Clear();
          Console.WriteLine("|Invetory|");
          Console.WriteLine("To change item, enter slot number");
          Console.WriteLine("To quit inventory, enter 9");
          for(int i = 0; i<backpack.Length; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Slot " + i + " |  " + backpack[i]);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
          pressedKey = Console.ReadLine();

            if(Int32.Parse(pressedKey) == i)
            {
              if(backpack[i] == null){
                income = 1;
              }else
              {
              strConvert = items[i,3];
              income = Int32.Parse(strConvert);
              }
            }          

          }
          break;
```

I thought i can get that items value with this code fragment `strConvert = items[i,3]; income = Int32.Parse(strConvert);`
With this code, if i get in backpack value 5 from item array, it stores in backpacks first value and when i choose this backpacks value(equip that item) then it returns me first value of Item array. Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: If you're stuck to using arrays ... then ignore this comment; but you might consider using dictionaries (Dictionary and/or SortedDictionary) - it would simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. I will keep this question, so others can check it out and learn something

```
Console.Clear();
          Console.WriteLine("|Invetory|");
          Console.WriteLine("To change item, enter slot number");
          Console.WriteLine("To quit inventory, enter 9");
          for(int i = 0; i<backpack.Length; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Slot " + i + " |  " + backpack[i]);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
          pressedKey = Console.ReadLine();
          for(int i = 0; i < backpack.Length; i++)
          {
            if(Int32.Parse(pressedKey) == i)
            {
              for(int x = 0; x < items.Length; x++)
              {
                if(backpack[i] == items[x, 0])
                {
                strConvert = items[x,3];
                income = Int32.Parse(strConvert);
                break;
                }
              }
            }          
          }
          break;
```